# Javascript assign page element to variable through javascript object class

Tags: javascript, class, object, dom

I am trying to assign the #Canvas css ID to a javascript variable inside my class function.  Basically I am tring to make it so that instead of going `document.getElementByID("someID").appendChild(anotherElement)` I can just go `page.Add(javascript_object)` When I execute the below page I get the following error: `" Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null"`.  What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
System.Web = {};
System.Web.UI={};
System.Web.UI.WebControls = {
Page: function (arg) {
    this.Node;
    this.Add = function (obj) {
        this.Node.appendChild(obj);
    }
    this.NodeCreate = function (args) {
        this.Node = document.getElementById(args);
    }
    this.NodeCreate(arg);
},
TextBoxMode:function(){
    this._MultiLine="";
    this.Password="password";
    this.SingleLine = "";
}
}
```

Then I call the object like this:

```
var x=document.createElement("div");
var page = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Page("canvas");//Note: canvas is my css ID
page.Add(x);
```

Comment: `createElement` is lowercase

Comment: fixed the typo but that still does not answer the question

Comment: If the typo exists in your source code, then @Bergi's comment _does_ answer your question. Looking at the JavaScript you posted I don't see any problems.

Comment: The problem is the following error when trying to execute it:
the following error: " Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null"

Comment: [We cannot reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/PhZxB/). Please provide a demo that exhibits the problem.